# This is Jorge, Be like Jorge

Tags: discussion, bounty

This is [Jorge](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro?tab=bounties&sort=offered),
Jorge offers bounties on other people's questions,
Jorge doesn't worry too much about reputation,
Jorge is smart,
Be like Jorge.

---

Anyway, the thing is, let's learn to offer bounties for other questions even if belonging to other users. That's the whole point of this, eh, 'question'. Don't be so focused on how much reputation you have, at the end of the day, it's all about the number of people we help.
Thank you.

Comment: Derived from the `this is bill meme` -> https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=this+is+bill

Comment: Hmm. I'd love to. Canonical, job please!

Comment: And that's when all us low rep scum suddenly started tagging @Jorge in our most desperate questions.

Comment: Perhaps we should create a tag: '@Jorge' so we don't have to ping him 

Comment: @DirkHaupt: That wouldn't actually work though because the person (as far as I understand) only gets notified if they have participated in discussion on the post or if they are its owner.

Comment: Oh we don't do it because we know he'll get the message. We do it for religious purposes, a good luck charm. Sometimes whether a question will get a good answer just feels so much left to fate that you might as well add @Jorge and go back to praying.

Comment: @Lnux Marking a duplicate does not decrease your reputation.

Comment: Wow. Now he has sacrificed 60k for bounties!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Never told this anyone, but Jorge is one of the main reasons that I finally stuck around here. He put a bounty on my [third question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229254/how-do-i-determine-an-applications-process-name) *ever*, in what is the pre- history in my AU experience, actually of my Ubuntu experience in general. I was impressed by the gesture, and felt honoured. I still am.

Does that mean that I should be like Jorge?

No. Jorge has the talent to find under- valued questions. I don't. Jorge has *the character* to look out for interesting questions outside his own area of interest. Even if I wanted, I simply don't have it in me.

There are numerous ways to be usefull around here. Some people ask excellent questions, others write excellent answer. Some people are excellent editors, others outstanding moderators. Everyone donating the best talents to the site, that's what makes it work.

Comment: True Jacob. We all just have to find where we fit. I don't mind giving my bounty on deserving cases, others just up-vote and that's cool of them, others may do reviews. Just find a place you fit in.

Comment: But whatever the case, Jorge is just awesome. He's the reason why I have stuck around for so long.

Comment: @Parto I second that!

Comment: Man you guys are awesome. You've made my weekend!  *hugs*

Comment: Great! So far you can be like Jorge, or Jacob. Any other types? What about the due that has a question, subscribes, asks, gets a satisfactory answer, and never come back? Let me take the liberty to call him/her Jiffy.

Comment: 432 offered bounties for 61,450 reputation, that's awesome, Jorge.

Comment: We have different gifts, according to the grace given to each of us. Jorge has [gift of giving](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans+12%3A6-8&version=NIV).